# Set a fixed size for symbology in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, scale

I'm looking for a way to set a fixed width for line symbols in ArcGIS Pro so that they remain the same actual on-ground size no matter what scale the map is currently at, instead of automatically increasing in width when viewing the map at smaller scales.

I'm designing a map for a scale of 1:15,000 but would like to be able to zoom out in the map view to look at a larger area without all the symbols being inflated.

i.e., I want a line designed to be say 1mm wide at 1:15000 to look 15mm wide if I zoom in to 1:1000, look 0.5mm wide if I zoom out to 1:30000, etc.

How can I do this?

[Lines correct at design scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITQEV.png)

[Lines too thin when zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDGXx.png)

[Lines too wide when zoomed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td2n4.png)

Comment: Have you tried setting the reference scale of the MAP to 1:15,000? It's under the general tab for properties of a map.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for, never knew about that setting.

Comment: Please answer your question rather that edit your question with Answered. Its not the way GIS works. Your allowed to Answer your own question.